# How turn on camera flash light with commonsware camera library

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, commonsware-cwac

I would like to know how to turn flash light with the commonsware camera library available at: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera

I guess i have to override in my camera host but this does not effect.

```
@Override
public Camera.Parameters adjustPreviewParameters(Camera.Parameters parameters)
{
    parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
    return super.adjustPreviewParameters(parameters);
}
```

Regards,

Comment: You want to enable flash mode? Or actually turn on the light? I think your code is heading towards the former

Answer (score 5):

You can try using `adjustPictureParameters()` instead of `adjustPreviewParameters()` and see if that helps. Since flash modes affect pictures, not preview, "official" support in CWAC-Camera for this would be in `adjustPictureParameters()`.

(though, in practice, I would expect either to work)

If that does not help, there's probably some bug where I'm interfering with matters.

Comment: OK, I'll have to take a look at this. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues/2

Comment: This is how all vendor support should work on Stack Overflow.  Someone with a high level of expertise monitors the tag, identifies the problem, and comes up with a fix within hours.  Kudos.